# Delete Records from Parent child table

Tags: postgresql

I want to delete records from the database tables and all are in relations.

A -> B -> c-> D

for example : College Table => degrees Table=> Courses Table=> sections table.

Now i want to delete college A from college table and its associated degrees and degrees assoicated with courses and courses associated with sections.

How can i efficiently delete the record.

DB : Postgres
Middle tier : SpringBoot with Java1.8

Comment: Add a foreign key on your tables with delete cascade [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK)

Answer (score 0):

If you define all your foreign key constrains with `on delete cascade`, Postgres will automatically take care of that.

```
create table college 
(
  id int primary key, 
  ... other columns ...
);

create table degree 
(
  id int primary key, 
  ... other columns ...
  college_id int not null, 
  constraint fk_degree_college 
     foreign key (college_id) 
     references college (id)
     ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Do the same for the `course` and `section` tables. Then if you delete a college, Postgres will automatically delete all referenced rows.